# How to add a button dynamically in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to add a button dynamically in Android using Kotlin?

I am new to Kotlin, please help.

Comment: What u have tried ?

Comment: @8hubham : kotlin is new language for android. you can search on google

Comment: Question was very basic thats main reason

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a button dynamically by calling the constructor of the button.

```
var myButton = Button(this);
```

'this' will be the activity.

Comment: i want to add button to another view. how to add them

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:-

/*
    Create a new Button programmatically in Kotlin Android
     */

```
private fun createButtonDynamically() {
    // creating the button
    val dynamicButton = Button(this)
    // setting layout_width and layout_height using layout parameters
    dynamicButton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    dynamicButton.text = "Dynamic Button"
    dynamicButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
    // add Button to LinearLayout
    mainLayout.addView(dynamicButton)


}
```

Comment: Please show where mainLayout coming from.

Comment: @zeeshan from something like `val mainLayout= findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.mainLayout)` depending on the view in your layout XML file